# Javascript sort array but each key is unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, key

For a chess app, I need to sort the elements of this object based on the value, in javascript:

```
const Moves = {e7e5: '-42', g8f6: '-16', h7h6: '-38', c8d7: '-29'};
```

Something along the lines:

```
Moves.sort((a,b)=>a.?? > b.??))
```

Whereby, the missing bit to get it to work is the ??.

Comment: That's not a valid array. Arrays don't have `key: value` format, that's only in objects.

Comment: The comparison function should return a number, not a boolean. It returns a negative number for less than, a positive number for greater than, and 0 for equal.

Comment: Maybe that should be an array of objects? Like `[{e7e5: -42}, ... ]`? The negative numbers should probably be actual numbers and not strings. To order that array, your comparator function can use `Object.entries()` to get the single key/value array from each object and then perform a comparison on the value (or `Object.values()` maybe if the key doesn't matter at all).

Comment: Your current data structure is unclear.  I'd suggest something like `let moves  = [{move: 'e7e5', score: -42}, ...]` and then `moves.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.values()` to get a value of a property regardless of its name in an object:

```js
const Moves = [{e7e5: '-42'}, {g8f6: '-16'}, {h7h6: '-38'}, {c8d7: '-29'}];

Moves.sort((a,b) => Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0]);

console.log(Moves);
```

Reversed:

```js
const Moves = [{e7e5: '-42'}, {g8f6: '-16'}, {h7h6: '-38'}, {c8d7: '-29'}];

Moves.sort((a,b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);

console.log(Moves);
```

Comment: Alex, Thanks. Why do we need the [0] index ?

Comment: @Cymro because Object.values() return an array of values of object properties. In our case we have 1 property, so access its value by `[0]`.

Comment: @Cymro If you find my answer useful don't forget to accept (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up), thanks https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Alex, I tried out your answer. How to switch the order of the sorting? Object.values(a)[0] - Object.values(b)[0]  <> Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]  both order in the same way.

Comment: @Cymro not the same, updated the answer, check pls

Answer (score -1):

movesArray.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b[1]) - parseInt(a[1]));
This will sort the moves in descending order based on the numeric values.